# Jquery post to php file works but can't return the data echoed in php

Tags: php, jquery, http-post

I can post the data using jquery (Checked with the mysql insert from that php file, it does insert, so i'm 100% sure that posting works), even though something is echoed in the php file, i can't seem to return that to the page with my data function (also checked if it echoes normally)... I know it should work, any ideas why it wouldn't?

```
$('#formbutton').click(function() {
var user = $('#nameinput').val();
$.post("usercount.php", {
    username: user
}, function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
});
```

Comment: javascript seems valid perfectly, can you provide a little code segment that shows how your php file echos data?

Comment: posted data goes to usercount.php, then $_POST['username'] goes to a php class:

    if ($visitors_online->count_users() == 1) {
  echo  ", There is " . $visitors_online->count_users() . " visitor online";
  
 } like that, thats when/how things are echoed

Comment: the odd thing is that jquery doesn't even alert("Data Loaded") alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is inserted, there should't be anything wrong with the request. My guess is that a fatal error occurs after the data is inserted, thus preventing the output. You should check your PHP logs for a clue.

You should also check the response code of the request in the Net panel in Firebug or similar tools. If the response fails, the callback function in $.post won't execute. Try using the $.ajax function instead, and provide both a success and an error callback.

Comment: Note that in order to receive a server response, the post needs to go to a URL on the same domain as the page. Otherwise the request will be sent but the response will be omitted by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems correct (or at least I can't see anything wrong now).

Use the network panel in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or chrome developer tools to inspect the request and the response of the ajax calls and see if they are correct (and also if the response comes with http status code 200). Also check the javascript console, put a breakpoint here or there and play with it (it's fun :D)